# Exception happened while loading schemas.json

Tags: dxa-2.0, dd4t-2, model-service, r2

I have a DD4T .NET web application using the DXA Model Service. The content is published as the DXA R2 data format.

This situation is supported:

[image]

Currently I am getting the following error:

```
2019-03-15 14:38:13,981 INFO  c.s.d.m.s.DefaultPageModelService - Found R2 model while requested DD4T, need to process R2 and convert, request PageRequestDto(publicationId=135, uriType=tcm, path=/index, includePages=INCLUDE, contentType=MODEL, dataModelType=DD4T, expansionDepth=100, depthCounter=com.sdl.dxa.common.dto.DepthCounter@9f) 
2019-03-15 14:38:14,226 ERROR c.s.d.m.s.ConfigService - Exception happened while loading schemas.json, cannot get schemas config, pub ID = 135 
com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.StaticContentNotFoundException: No binary meta found for: [135] /system/mappings/schemas.json
```

I am happy that the error is so clear, but as far as I know, the schemas.json is not part of the DXA installation media:

[image]

How can I create this page myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DXA **[PublishMappings](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/release/2.0/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates/Templates/PublishMappings.cs)** TBB. That TBB Publishes schema and region mapping information in JSON format.

In DXA if you publish the **Publish Settings** page with Core (Module Configuration) component then in the background, These binaries are named like **schemas.json** are getting published and also have that name (excl. file extension) as variant ID to Broker DB.

In your case, I think you have to create **Publish Settings** page with the module configuration component and to publish the page so that you will be able to get the schemas.json

[image]

I hope it helps.